# Yii2 Bootstrap Modal backdrop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I've created modal window using Yii2 bootstrap Modal. The default behaviour of Modal is if you click outside the modal area, the modal will automatically close. I want to prevent that behaviour means it should not close the modal window when clicking outside the modal.

Following is my Yii2 Modal Code:

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h4>Disapprove Request</h4>',
    'id' => 'disapproveModal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'class' => 'bg-gray',    
]);
?>

<div class="showmsg" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label>Please select the reason of disapproval. Click on "Disapprove" to proceed and click on "Cancel" to remove dialog</label>
    <input type="text" name="disappr_txt" id="disappr_text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter reason of disapproval" required>
</div>
<br/>

<?= Html::submitButton('Disapprove', ['class' => 'disapprovebtn btn btn-primary', 'value' => 'disapprove', 'name' => 'submit']); ?>            
<?= Html::a('Close', 'javascript:void(0);', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary closebutton', 'aria-hidden' => "true", 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) ?>

<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

As mentioned in twitter bootstrap site I've added `backdrop=>static` and `keyboard=>false` in JQuery modal options but still it not working and modal is getting closed after clicking on outside of modal area.

Following is my JQuery Code:

```
$(".showDisapproveModal").click(function () {
    $("#disapproveModal").modal({
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'
    }).find('modalContent').load($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Comment: I don't see the HTML code for `#disaproveModal`. I also don't see the `.showDisapproveModal` button. It could be that the modal is showing and using its natural open and close behavior, and not even using your JQuery.

Answer (score 7):

I also faced this issue. I enabled to solve that issue using the code

```
'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => false]
```

in the `Modal:begin()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h4>Disapprove Request</h4>',
    'id' => 'disapproveModal',
    'size' => 'modal-lg',
    'class' => 'bg-gray', 
    'clientOptions' => ['backdrop' => 'static', 'keyboard' => false],
]);
?>
```

Add clientOptions as per Win Naung's answer in Modal